# How to create html page template and bind controller to it dynamically with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to create html template and bind correspondent controller to it dynamically.

How can I do it with AngularJS?

I can create dynamic template with $compile service, but I don't know how to bind a controller to it in an efficient and elegant way.

Details.

I want to create a popup menu. I made a service with a method `onPopupShowEventHandler(event, data)`. This method will create a simple piece of html code with some behaviour and insert it into the body of my main html code. Behaviour I'm getting from outside. And that exact behaviour depends on the situation.

So, now I'm able to create piece of html code with $compile service, but I want to put a controller into the ng-controller section of this html code. I don't know how to do it...

Code.

```
onPopupShowEventHandler = function(event, data) {

        var menuItems = data.popupMenuItems; // I want this elements to be accessible in 'element'

        pair = data.pair;

        var element =   '<div id="popup" style=\"' + menuStyle + '\">'+
                        '<ul>'+
                        '<li ng-repeat="item in menuItems"><a href="" ng-click="delegateInvoker($index)">{{item.name}}</a></li>'+
                        '</ul>'+
                        '</div>';

        element = angular.element(element);

        var overlayCSS = {
            left: data.clientX + offset.left + 'px',
            top: data.clientY + offset.top + 'px',
            display: 'block'
        };

            var compiled = $compile(element)($rootScope);
            compiled.css(overlayCSS);
            var body = angular.element('body');
            body.append(compiled);
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and an example. As is, this question doesn't give a lot to go on.

Comment: What about: var element =   '<div ng-controller="mycontroller" id="popup" style=\"' + menuStyle + '\">'+

Comment: Will not work. I don't have 'mycontroller' and even if I'll create it inside of onPopupShowEventHandler like a simple function, this is not enough to bind it to html template.

Comment: A service is not the place to manipulate the DOM, you need to do this inside a directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a directive and then binding a controller to it and then putting the directive as attribute in your template 
check this link 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2603-directive-controller-and-link-timing-in-angularjs.htm